# how to set all images into imageViews from ArrayList<string>

Tags: java, android

I have selected images from the gallery using Pix library, now I need to set these `base64` converted images to image views, it works but the app crashes when I select a single image,

```
 if (encodedImageList != null) {
        //first image
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImageList.get(0), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    }

    if (encodedImageList.get(1) != null) {

        //2nd image
        byte[] decodedString2 = Base64.decode(encodedImageList.get(1), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString2, 0, decodedString2.length);
        imageView2.setImageBitmap(decodedByte2);
    }
 if (encodedImageList.get(2) != null) {

        //3rd image
        byte[] decodedString3 = Base64.decode(encodedImageList.get(2), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte3 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString3, 0, decodedString3.length);
        imageView3.setImageBitmap(decodedByte3);
    }
```

Comment: post your error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading images into memory is very risky because or running out of memory. The best way is to use something like **Glide/Picasso** to load images into `ImageView`.

Comment: i need to upload this array to server thats why i am converting it to base64, all i want to do to display selected images before uploading like whatsapp

Comment: First display using Glide/Picasso and then upload. I would even suggest do the base64 conversion on the server rather than on app.

Comment: yeah that worked ,was really better option .thankyou

Answer (score 0):

create `ImageView`s dynamically based on your list `encodedImageList` and store all the references in array imageViews and replace your logic to this.

```
    if (encodedImageList != null) {
            for(int i =0; i<encodedImageList.size();i++){
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImageList.get(i), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            imageViews[i].setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps